# I need more memory!

Tags: memory-usage

I am trying to make a RBB Arduino based project and I only need 3 pins. In the future I may use one to two more. I wanted to use an ATtiny85 however my code is 13,270 bytes and it would not fit. So I decided to use an ATtiny84 but it also would not fit, it will fit on an ATmega328p but I do not want to use one because i want to keep the project relatively small and I for sure do not need that many pins. Does anyone know of a chip that has a lot of memory but not many pins, or some other solution. Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Atmel's parametric search tool yet?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, 8 KiB of flash is the most you can have on an AVR in a DIP
package with less than 28 pins. If you do not mind soldering
surface-mount parts, the 328P is available in TQFP and VQFN packages,
significantly smaller than the DIP version.

Otherwise you could try to optimize your program to fit in 8 KiB.
The Arduino libraries are often inefficient size-wise, and in many
instances you can save quite a lot by rewriting the parts that you need
on top of just [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/). Note that
this libc is always linked to your program by the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Ok, I tried to optimize my code but could not get it much smaller. I guess my best option is to use a TQFP version, I didn't think about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to optimize your code and reduce the size. Have a look on this document from Atmel. I've used some tips to reduce the size of my bootloader once.

http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8453.pdf

For the AVR family I'm not familiar with any option. You could use a small QFN package for the atmega328p as well... You might find some small ARM with much more memory and small size.